# delete_option() не успевает удалить запись с БД до загрузки страницы

Tags: wordpress

Нужно удалить опции с БД до загрузки страницы. Представленный код снизу не успевает сделать это.

ФРОНТ

```
$( '#escape' ).click( function() {
    $.post( ajaxurl, { action: 'exit_pref' }, function( ready ) {
        if ( ready ) location.href = url
    } )
} );
```

БЕК

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_exit_pref', 'exit_pref' );

function exit_pref() {
    delete_option( 'data_pref' );
}
```

ФРОНТ (успевает загрузить data)

```
<?php $select = wp_unslash( get_option( 'data_pref' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Ну так может имеет смысл отправить какой-то ответ с сервера после удаления опции? `if(delete_option('data') { wp_send_json_success('Deleted'); }` и в случае успешного удаления уже перенаправлять на другую страницу.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам необходимо выполнить какой-то код до загрузки страницы, то логично использовать хук, который срабатывает до загрузки страницы.
Например, довольно универсально будет использовать хук [wp](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/), который срабатывает сразу после определения глобальной переменной `$wp`

Кроме того, стоит избегать именования функций зарезервированными словами, в данном случае это `exit`, в php эта функция уже [определена](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exit.php) и попытки создания своей с таким же именем будут приводить к ошибкам

В итоге имеем что-то вроде:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp', 'myprefix_exit' );

function myprefix_exit() {
    delete_option( 'data' );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно чтобы данные были удалены после нажатия на кнопку, то логично было бы дождаться ответа от сервера, были ли удалены данные.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_exit_pref', 'exit_pref' );

function exit_pref() {
    if( delete_option('data') ) { 
        wp_send_json_success('Deleted');
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Внутри вашего аякс запроса добавьте так же проверку для `data.success`.

```
$( '#escape' ).click( function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'exit_pref'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.success) {
                location.href = url
            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

В целом, запрос немного странноват, так как по-сути вы никаких данных на сервер не передаете.

И вообще почитайте про [Ajax в WordPress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html). Есть ряд вещей про которые я не стал писать, но неплохо бы чтобы они были, я говорю о nonce, к примеру. Не стоит принебрегать безопасностью.